# Unable to pass an object to chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was working on my extension using chrome local storage and i wanted to clear local cache so i used `chrome.storage.local.clear()`. Now i want to add more data to local storage using `chrome.storage.local.set()` but it returns undefined when passing an object even though it did work before the clear.

This works

```
chrome.storage.local.set({key: 'value'})

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], result => {
    console.log(result.key) // returns value
})
```

But this doesn't

```
const obj = {
    key: 'value'
}

chrome.storage.local.set(obj)

chrome.storage.local.get(['obj'], result => {
    console.log(result.obj) // returns undefined
})
```

I need to be able to pass an object to `chrome.storage.local.set`

Comment: The observed behavior is correct. Look at `{key: 'value'}` in your first example - it is an object just the same as `obj` in the second example and both set the property named `key` to the specified value so you need to get `'key'` just the same. To save an object specify it instead of `'value'`.

Comment: `get(['obj']`, Your key name is still `key` not `obj`. The `set()` doesn't use the variable's name, as it has no way of knowing it

Comment: `console.log(result.obj.key)` still returns undefined

Comment: `result.key` not `result.obj` nor `result.obj.key` you have no property named `obj`. Only a varible whose name is `obj` which is not used at all for the local storage. Your get should be `get(['key']` in both situations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are setting the object, the key name is set as `key` only. But you are having an issue because you are trying to access key name `obj` which does not exist. You can access the key-value like this:

```
const obj = { key: 'value'}

chrome.storage.local.set(obj);

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], result => {
    console.log(result.key) // returns 'value'
})
```

For more info:

- [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)

**For storing an object in `chrome.storage`:**

```
const name: {
   first: 'Bob',
   last: 'Smith'
}

chrome.storage.local.set({ key: name });

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], result => {
   console.log(result.key) // returns { first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith' }
   console.log(result.key.first)
   console.log(result.key.last)
})
```

You can also destructure the `result` object to get the keys like:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], ({key}) => {
   console.log(key) // returns { first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith' }
   console.log(key.first)
   console.log(key.last)
})
```

**Get the entire contents of storage**

As mentioned in the [documentaion](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#StorageArea-methods):

> A single key to get, list of keys to get, or a dictionary specifying default values (see description of the object). An empty list or object will return an empty result object. **Pass in null to get the entire contents of storage.**

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
   var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
   console.log(allKeys);
});
```

Comment: The real object i'm using has multiple keys, i don't want to specify all keys in the `get(['key']` array as that would take too much time. I swear it worked fine for me earlier but after .clear() it all got messed up and i'm not sure what to do now.

I need to be able to access it like `obj.key, obj.secondKey` etc

Comment: I have shared an example you can try that out.

Comment: @vcosiekx Pass in `null` to get the entire storage without needing to specify keys, eg `get(null,...`